# RGCN using source and targets of edges for aggregation

Tags: pytorch-geometric

I am checking an old TF v1 repository (https://github.com/microsoft/tf-gnn-samples) and trying to do the same thing in PyG.
I see RGCN implementation has an option that says if it should get only neighborhoud for aggregation or it should pair the neighbour with the central node and pass them together.

```
if use_both_source_and_target:
                edge_target_states = \
                    tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=cur_node_states,
                                           ids=edge_targets)  # Shape [E, H]
                edge_state_pairs = tf.concat([edge_source_states, edge_target_states], axis=-1)  # Shape [E, 2H]
                messages = edge_type_to_message_transformation_layers[edge_type_idx](edge_state_pairs)  # Shape [E, H]
            else:
                messages = edge_type_to_message_transformation_layers[edge_type_idx](edge_source_states)  # Shape [E, H]
```

I am trying to figure out how this is done in Pytorch Geometric.